# TFS Build DOS command

Tags: tfs

We have a TFS (2012) project that we use as a PL/SQL source code repository.  This project does not contain any .Net code or solution just PL/SQL code.

We have a command line build process & deploy process to move the PL/SQL code to the database.  Currently we are running the command line daily by hand.  I would really like TFS to kick off the command line daily.

I have created a custom TFS Build Process Timeplate that just contains an Invoke Process function however when I go to create a new TFS Build Definition it requires me to fill in Items to Build. I do not have any items to build I just want to kick off the Build Process template.

Is there any way to create a striped down TFS Build that will just run the Invoke Process and not worry about the Items to Build?

Comment: You may want to consider using a deployment tool -- TFS2013 has a release management tool shipping with it.

Answer (score 0):

You have made the good choice, but your custom activity Invoke Process must be integrated to your main build, items correspond to your solution c#.
So when you create your build, you compile your items, and in the end you execute your check for pl sql.